# How do I access the data from a file passed as parameters in a RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Following the last example on RMarkdown's [Parametrized Reports](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) page, I am trying to use the `Shiny` interface to select my input file with the following code inside the `YAML` header:

```
params:  
  data:  
    input: file  
    label: 'Input dataset:'  
    value: myData.csv
```

The `Shiny` interface shows up and I get to browse for a file, but when I try to access it further down in the `R` code via `read.csv(file=params$data, header=TRUE)`, I get the following message:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

How can I get to read my file?

*Note*: I have seen a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479130/passing-parameters-to-r-markdown) where users pass the file path in a function at the time of rendering the `RMarkdown` document, but this is not what I am trying to do. I would just like to be able to select it from the `Shiny` interface.

**EDIT**
After playing a bit more, I think the issue is that the temporary file created when reading the file I select via the `shiny` interface and passed as params$data doesn't exist anymore when I try to access it.
Indeed, `file.exists(params$data)` returns `FALSE`.

So I guess my question now becomes: How do I get to read this temporary file before it is erased ?

Comment: Quite sure this is a bug in the system. I reported this to the RStudio crew, but no answer yet.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the file as you would had you been using a Shinyapp? Usually, the object created by fileInput is not the path to the file. The actual path would be, in your case, `params$data$datapath` or maybe `params$datapath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like this can be reproduced anymore.

Just for the sake of explaining how this is done:

1. Create a new RMarkdown document
2. Add the following yaml block to the top:

   ```
   params:  
     data:  
       input: file  
       label: 'Input dataset:'  
       value: myData.csv
   ```
3. Add the following R chunk to the document:

   ````
   ```{r data}
   cat(params$data)
   c <- read.csv(params$data)
   print(c)
   ```
   ````
4. Select under the "Knit" dropdown the "Knit with Parameters" option
5. Attach any valid CSV and click "Knit" in the Shiny parameters panel

Comment: Is it possible to access the original file path? I am working on a report where I need to log the file location and timestamp.