# Rmarkdown Parameterized Reports - Can't access data from selected file

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have exactly the same problem as defined in a previous post ([How do I access the data from a file passed as parameters in a RMarkdown document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436515/how-do-i-access-the-data-from-a-file-passed-as-parameters-in-a-rmarkdown-documen/36932729?noredirect=1#comment61427372_36932729)), and I don't find (StackOverflow, google...) any clue to solve it !

With the default filename, it works! With the selected file (which could be the same file), I get an error.

```
Quitting from lines 51-51 (WBD_MCS.Rmd) 
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv2 -> read.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\SESA40~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaMmix8/a6232463beeca55dd111a939/0': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

I have the problem on MacOSX and Windows.

```
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) -- "Very, Very Secure Dishes"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

If someone can share a solution...

The header of my .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Simulation de Monte Carlo pour une estimation Wideband Delphi"
author: "Alain BRET"
date: "28 avril 2016"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      before_body: tex/tex_before_body.tex
      in_header: tex/tex_header.tex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
  word_document:
    toc: yes
params:
  nombre_occurences:
    input: slider
    label: "Nombre d'occurences:"
    max: 10000
    min: 1000
    step: 500
    value: 1000
  datafile:
    input: file
    label: 'Fichier des estimations des Experts:'
    value: data/estimation_data_2.csv
---
```

Comment: Just for the record: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/919 (we will try to fix it at some point). Thanks!

Comment: With rmakdown v1.7, it works now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been reported to [rstudio/rmarkdown#919](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/919) and fixed in the version 1.7 of the **rmarkdown** package. It should suffice to `install.packages('rmarkdown')`.